Expansion of Gaussian Hypergeometric Function for Large Third Parameter - new formula?
I am looking at the asymptotic expansion of the Gaussian hypergeometric function for large third parameter ($\lambda \rightarrow \infty$), which is given by
$$
_{2}F_{1}(a,b;\gamma+\lambda;z)\ \overset{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}{\sim} \ \frac{\Gamma(\gamma+\lambda)}{\Gamma(\gamma-b+\lambda) \ \lambda^{b}} \ \sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\ f_{s}(a,b,\gamma,z) \ \frac{(b)_{s}}{\lambda^{s}}
$$
in https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12.E3 (with a slight change of notation by me).
The coefficients $f_s$ are defined via the generating function
$$
f(A,B,C,Z,t)=\left(1-Z+Z e^{-t}\right)^{-A} \ \left( \frac{e^{t}-1}{t}  \right)^{B-1} \ e^{(1-C)t}\ .
$$ by
$$  
f(A,B,C,Z,t)=\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\ f_{s}(A,B,C,Z) t^{s}.
$$
After some experimentation with algebraic software I found an alternative formula
$$
_{2}F_{1}(a,b;\gamma+\lambda;z)\  \overset{\lambda \rightarrow \infty}{\sim}\ \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \ (-1)^{s}\, \lambda^{-s} \ \sum_{r=0}^{s} \ \frac{(a)_{r}\,(b)_{r}}{r!}\ (-z)^{r} \ {{s-1}\choose{r-1}} B_{s-r}^{(-r+1)}(\gamma), (*)
$$
where $B_{n}^{(\alpha)}(x)$ are the generalized Bernoulli polynomials, defined via the generating function
$$
e^{x t}\left(\frac{t}{e^{t}-1}\right)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ B_{n}^{(\alpha)}(x)\,\frac{t^{n}}{n!}.
$$
Definition of the Pochhammer symbols are as usual
$$
(a)_{n} = \frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(a)}.
$$
But I am not able to prove it.

Question : How to prove my new suggestion $(*)$ for the asymptotic expansion of the Gaussian Hypergeometric Function in the third parameter ?
